# Why is printf(inputString) a security hole?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, printf

I was reading an answer on Quora where I encountered that something as simple as:

```
char* inputString;
printf(inputString);
```

is a security hole.

I assume that the inputString is not simply uninitialized, but initialized with some external input between the two statements.

How *exactly* is this a security hole?

The original answer on Quora was here:

> [If C and C++ give the best performance, why do we still code in other languages?](http://qr.ae/Rwqbvk)

but it provides no additional context for this claim.

Comment: Thanks, I started reading http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf for the reference but I can't really understand why everyone is down-voting the question.

Comment: @Lundin I disagree. Of course, it could be mentioned more explicitly, but naming a variable "inputString" in a very short example makes it quite clear that the purpose of the variable is holding input data. Looking at http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf also makes it quite clear how this is a security hole, and not a simple bug...

Comment: @Lundin: the "muppet" and "blog dummy" got 254 upvotes for that answer. I'm not a Quora member, I don't know how voting works there, but I'd say it's hard to dismiss him as an incompetent. And if you have a look at the answers here you'll see that many users agree that it is, indeed, a security hole, at least in one case (if it contains unsanitized user input). That said, let's get back to the issue: the OP stumbled upon a statement that he found surprising (as you said, it looks like a normal bug, not a security hole), so he decided to ask about it. How can that be wrong?

Comment: Related: [How is printf() in C/C++ a Buffer overflow vulnerability?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/43574/230952)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*I assume that the input string is a string you got from the user, and not just an uninitialized value.*

The problem is that the user can

- crash the program: `printf ("%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s%s")`
- view the stack: `printf ("%08x %08x %08x %08x %08x\n");`
- view memory on any location,
- or even write an integer to nearly any location in the process memory.

This leads to an attacker being able to:

- Overwrite important program flags that control access privileges
- Overwrite return addresses on the stack, function pointers, etc

It is all explained quite well [here](http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/Teaching/cis643/LectureNotes_New/Format_String.pdf).

Answer (score 8):

It's not just a security problem, but it won't work at all, because the pointer is not initialized. In this context, making the program crash = not running anymore could be a (security) problem, depending what the program does and in what context it runs.

I assume you mean you have a proper string. In this case, if the string is provided by some external input (user etc.), there can be (unexpected) placeholders like %s etc. while the rest of the printf expects eg. a %d. For this example (%s instead of %d), instead of printing an integer number, it will start printing all memory content until some 0 byte then, possibly giving out some secret information stored after the int bytes.

Something similar, ie. giving out too much bytes because of wrong unchecked user input, happened eg. in the known "Heartbleed" bug not too long ago, which was/is a pretty big global problem. ... The first printf parameter should be fixed, not coming from any variable.

Other placeholder combinations are possible too, leading to a wide range of possible effects (including generation of wrong floating point signals in the CPU, which could lead to more serious problems depending on the architecture, etc.etc.)

Comment: Or it could even contain `%n` format specifiers and start writing to unexpected memory...

Answer (score 1):

```
char* inputSting; 
printf(inputSting);
```

Printing out an uninitialized string is undefined behavior. Effects from undefined behavior can range from printing garbage values to segfaults and other nastyness. Such unpredictable patterns can be exploited and thus compromise security.

But more importantly, nobody would write this as it doesn't do anything meaningful besides risk a segfault.